# How to solve a logarithmic inequality?

Tags: inequality

I mean
 $$\left(\log _{\frac{3 x^2}{2}-\frac{4 x}{3}+\frac{5}{6}}\left(4 x^2+1\right) \log _{\frac{3 x^2}{2}-\frac{4 x}{3}+\frac{5}{6}}\left(1-4 x^2\right)+1\right) \log _{1-16 x^4}\left(\frac{3 x^2}{2}-\frac{4 x}{3}+\frac{5}{6}\right)\geq 1. $$
My (unsuccessful) try was to replace $\log _{1-16 x^4}\left(\frac{3 x^2}{2}-\frac{4 x}{3}+\frac{5}{6}\right) $ by $\frac 1 {\log _{\frac{3 x^2}{2}-\frac{4 x}{3}+\frac{5}{6}}\left(1-16 x^4\right)} $ and to determine the domains of the logarithms. My Mathematica 12.0 is running for hours without any result, solving it.

Comment: Are you missing a sign between the first two logarithms?

Comment: @Andrew Chin: Yes,  $\log _{\frac{3 x^2}{2}-\frac{4 x}{3}+\frac{5}{6}}\left(4 x^2+1\right) \log _{\frac{3 x^2}{2}-\frac{4 x}{3}+\frac{5}{6}}\left(1-4 x^2\right)$ is the product of two logarithms. Up to usual conventions, the multiplication sign is omitted. Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.

Comment: Lovely; was thinking that it would be simpler if there was a $+$ sign between the two logs.

Comment: @ Andrew Chin: My notation is clear and your guess is not true.

Comment: Maybe you have made a typo, check your inequality!

Comment: @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner: This is a nonstandard inequality.

Comment: Why on earth would you need to solve something like that? Just wondering...

Comment: @user64494: To make notation even clearer, I would recommend defining, say, $a := \frac32x^2-\frac43x+\frac56$, $b := 4x^2+1$, $c:=1-4x^2$. Then the problem, as written, would be $$(\log_ab \log_a c+1)\log_{bc}a \geq 1$$ From there ... well ... I believe I'm with @ Andrew in suspecting that the first factor might be intended to be $\log_ab+\log_a c + 1$, for which the problem has a straightforward solution. ... Please provide the source of the problem to give an idea of the expected level of difficulty.

Comment: @Blue: Thank you for your interest to the question. This is a problem from a Russian school math olympiad.

Comment: And which Russian school math olympiad was it? Do you have the original source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably wouldn't be ethical to complete the argument in
mathlove's answer, when he/she/they* has/have chosen to leave it as a hint.

(*I hope I haven't just violated the new Code of Conduct!) :)

Nevertheless, because a non-obvious further subdivision into cases
seems to be required, I hope that it's all right to add a few more
observations, using the same notation, without actually giving a
full answer.

First, for the problem to be well-posed, we must have $0 < h < 1$, i.e. $0 < |x| < \tfrac12$.

For the same reason, we must have $f > 0$ - but this is always true, because:
$$
f = \tfrac32\left(x - \tfrac49\right)^2 + \tfrac{29}{54}
> 0 \text{ for all } x.
$$

Next,
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:3436949:1}\tag{1}
f - 1 = \tfrac32x^2 - \tfrac43x - \tfrac16 = \tfrac32(x - 1)\left(x + \tfrac19\right).
\end{equation}

If $x = -\tfrac19$, then $f = 1$, and the problem is ill-posed.

So, for the problem to make sense, we must assume:
$$
-\tfrac12 < x < -\tfrac19 \text{ or }
{-\tfrac19} < x < 0 \text{ or }
0 < x < \tfrac12.
$$

In \eqref{eq:3436949:1}, the factor $x - 1$ is always strictly
negative, therefore:
\begin{gather*}
\text{if } x < -\tfrac19 \text{ then } f > 1; \\
\text{if } x > -\tfrac19 \text{ then } f < 1.
\end{gather*}

We have $0 < h < 1$ and $0 < gh < 1$, therefore:
\begin{gather*}
\text{if } f > 1 \text{ then }
\log_fh < 0 \text{ and } \log_f(gh) < 0; \\
\text{if } f < 1 \text{ then }
\log_fh > 0 \text{ and } \log_f(gh) > 0.
\end{gather*}

The two cases distinguished in mathlove's answer therefore correspond
to the alternatives $x > -\tfrac19$ and $x < -\tfrac19$, in that order.

In both cases, we need to compare $f$ with $g$, and to compare $f$ with $h$.

To this end, these two factorisations are helpful:
\begin{gather}
\label{eq:3436949:2}\tag{2}
g - f = \tfrac52x^2 + \tfrac43x + \tfrac16 =
\tfrac52\left(x + \tfrac13\right)\left(x + \tfrac15\right); \\
\label{eq:3436949:3}\tag{3}
f - h = \tfrac{11}2x^2 - \tfrac43x - \tfrac16 =
\tfrac{11}2\left(x - \tfrac13\right)\left(x + \tfrac1{11}\right).
\end{gather}
An answer can now be given by considering separately the cases
$-\tfrac12 < x < -\tfrac13$, $x = -\tfrac13$,
$-\tfrac13 < x < -\tfrac15$, $x = -\tfrac15$,
$-\tfrac15 < x < -\tfrac19$,
$-\tfrac19 < x < -\tfrac1{11}$, $x = -\tfrac1{11}$,
$-\tfrac1{11} < x < 0$,
$0 < x < \tfrac13$, $x = \tfrac13$,
$\tfrac13 < x < \tfrac12$,
perhaps amalgamating some pairs of neighbouring cases.

Comment: If I haven't miscalculated, the inequality is true for $$x \in
\left(-\tfrac12, -\tfrac13\right] \cup
\left[-\tfrac15, -\tfrac19\right) \cup
\left[-\tfrac1{11}, 0\right) \cup
\left(0, \tfrac13\right],$$ and false for $$x \in
\left(-\tfrac13, -\tfrac15\right) \cup
\left(-\tfrac19, -\tfrac1{11}\right) \cup
\left(\tfrac13, \tfrac12\right).$$

Comment: Nice answer. I've added some details in my answer, and my answer agrees with yours. So, it is likely that our answer is correct.

Comment: Finishing this answer, in the light of mathlove's now-finished answer:

If $x>-\tfrac19$, then $f<1<g$, therefore $\log_fg<0$, and the inequality $$(\log_fg-1)(\log_fh-1)\geqslant0$$ reduces to $\log_fh\leqslant1$, i.e. $f\leqslant h$, i.e. $f-h\leqslant0$, which by (3) is equivalent to $-\tfrac1{11}\leqslant x\leqslant\tfrac13$.

If $x<-\tfrac19$, then $f>1>h$, therefore $\log_fh<0$, and the inequality $$(\log_fg-1)(\log_fh-1)\leqslant0$$ reduces to $\log_fg\geqslant1$, i.e. $f\leqslant g$, i.e. $g-f\geqslant0$, which by (2) is equivalent to $x\leqslant-\tfrac13$ or $x\geqslant-\tfrac15$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$f=\frac{3 x^2}{2}-\frac{4 x}{3}+\frac{5}{6},\quad g=4x^2+1,\quad h=1-4x^2$$

Then, your inequality is

$$\left(\log _{f}\left(g\right) \log _{f}\left(h\right)+1\right) \log _{gh}\left(f\right)\geq 1, $$
i.e.
$$\left(\log _{f}\left(g\right) \log _{f}\left(h\right)+1\right)\frac{1}{\log _{f}(gh)}\geq 1\tag1$$

By the way, we have to have
$$f\gt 0,f\not=1,g\gt 0,h\gt 0,gh\not=1,$$
i.e.
$$x\in \left(-\frac{1}{2},-\frac 19\right)\cup \left(-\frac 19,0\right)\cup\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)\tag2$$

Now, let us separate it into two cases :

**Case 1** : If $\log_f(gh)\gt 0$, then
$$\begin{align}(1)&\iff \log _{f}\left(g\right) \log _{f}\left(h\right)+1\ge \log_f(g)+\log_f(h)\\\\&\iff (\log _{f}\left(g\right)-1)(\log _{f}\left(h\right)-1)\ge 0\tag3\end{align}$$

Here, noting that $gh=1-16x^2\lt 1$ under $(2)$, we have 
$$\log_f(gh)\gt 0\iff f\lt 1\iff x\in\left(-\frac 19,0\right)\cup\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)\tag4$$

Also, noting that $f-g=-\frac{1}{6}(5x+1)(3x+1)\lt 0$ under $(4)$, we have $\log_f(g)-1\lt 0$.

So, we have
$$(3)\iff \log _{f}\left(h\right)-1\le 0\iff f-h=\frac 16(3x-1)(11x+1)\le 0$$

So, in this case, we have
$$x\in \bigg[-\frac{1}{11},0\bigg)\cup\bigg(0,\frac 13\bigg]$$

**Case 2** : If $\log_f(gh)\lt 0$, then
$$(1)\iff (\log _{f}\left(g\right)-1)(\log _{f}\left(h\right)-1)\le 0\tag5$$

Since $gh\lt 1$, we have
$$\log_f(gh)\lt 0\iff f\gt 1\iff x\in\left(-\frac{1}{2},-\frac 19\right)\tag6$$
Also, noting that $f-h=\frac 16(3x-1)(11x+1)\gt 0$ under $(6)$, we have $\log_f(h)-1\lt 0$.

So, we have
$$(5)\iff \log_f(g)-1\ge 0\iff f-g=-\frac{1}{6}(5x+1)(3x+1)\le 0$$

So, in this case, we have
$$x\in \bigg(-\frac{1}{2},-\frac 13\bigg]\cup\bigg[-\frac 15,-\frac 19\bigg)$$

Therefore, the answer is
$$\color{red}{x\in \bigg(-\frac{1}{2},-\frac 13\bigg]\cup\bigg[-\frac 15,-\frac 19\bigg)\cup\bigg[-\frac{1}{11},0\bigg)\cup\bigg(0,\frac 13\bigg]}$$

Comment: Thank you. Can you kindly finish your solution? TIA.

Comment: @user64494: I've finished my solution (I gave a hint because I didn't have enough time). Anyway, my answer agrees with Calum Gilhooley's answer. So, it is likely that our answer is correct.

Comment: It was a bit of a cliffhanger, and I had plenty of time on my hands! Even so, I left my answer hanging in the air a bit, too. You've resolved it all neatly, and now I feel more confident of the solution. I've adapted your neat conclusion as a comment on my own answer.

Answer (score -1):

Hint: It simplifies to
$$\frac{\ln(4x^2+1)\ln(1-4x^2)}{\ln(1-16x^4)\ln(\frac{3}{2}x^2-\frac{4}{3}x+\frac{5}{6})}+\frac{\ln(\frac{3}{2}x^2-\frac{4}{3}x+\frac{5}{6})}{\ln(1-16x^4)}\geq 1$$
And this is $$\frac{1}{\ln(1-16x^4)}\left(\frac{\ln(4x^2+1)\ln(1-4x^2)}{\ln(\frac{3}{4}x^2-\frac{4}{3}x+\frac{5}{6})}+\ln(\frac{3}{2}x^2-\frac{4}{3}x+\frac{5}{6})\right)\geq 1$$

Comment: That's great. What's the next? TIA.